# Linux-NTP: What could cause high offset in some servers while all of them reside on the same network sigment and are configured the same?

Tags: centos6, ntp

I've installed a new NTP server and configured all Hadoop clients to use it.
I've been told by the Hadoop Engineers that an offset of maximum 3 seconds is mandatory for the cluster to work properly.

The server's NTP configuration is identical on all servers as it was installed and configured through Puppet and all servers use the same NTP server and they all reside in the same network segment.

When I ran `ntpq -p` on all servers I saw that there's a major difference in some servers, and that the offset is way too high.

Example:

```
hadoop-dn01.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   90  128  377    0.372   -9.163  24.699
hadoop-dn02.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   19   64  377    0.367    6.632   6.050
hadoop-dn03.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u    2   64  377    0.330    1.191   8.421
hadoop-dn04.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   40   64  377    0.367   11.323   8.563
hadoop-dn05.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u    9   64  377    0.329    7.353   7.845
hadoop-dn06.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   56   64  377    0.317   -0.919   6.757
hadoop-dn07.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   24   64  377    0.405  -12.100   9.447
hadoop-dn08.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   62   64  377    1.539    3.186   8.965
hadoop-jn01.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   12   64   37    0.446    5.457   3.623
hadoop-jn02.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   50   64   17    0.679   -3.492   3.632
hadoop-nn01.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u   23   64   17    0.642    5.943   3.939
hadoop-nn02.company.com
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adnj12.domain. 10.31.0.12       3 u    4   64   17    0.664    8.031   5.690
```

What could be the cause for the differences in the offsets and how can I decrease this offset?

Comment: You know those values are in milliseconds right?  How long ago did you set this up?  NTP doesn't immediately change the time, it will slowly adjust the time.  BTW, for reliability you really should have at least 3 NTP servers configured.

Comment: I'm actually not that familiar with NTP so it's good to know it's milliseconds rather than seconds. I've set it up about 20 minutes before asking the question and I thank you for the extra info regarding the reliability, if you'll create an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.